# How to make an image responsive using CSS?

Tags: responsive-design, image-scaling

How do you make an image responsive, such that it keeps its proportions as you change the screen size? i.e. if I have a book cover in the center right of an image (as in the header image here http://julianadorney.com/), how do I keep the book cover at roughly the same point in the image on different screens?

I've jury-rigged something using about 30 different media queries of min-height and min-width, but it seems like there should be a much more elegant solution.

I tried width: 100% and height: auto; no luck

Please, no Javascript. I won't know what it is...

Thanks in advance,
Julian

Comment: Have you tried a div containing the image and then the image height: 100% and width 100%? If you change the div measures, the image should rescale properly

Comment: Why not put it as a div background and play with cover, contain or percentages?

Answer (score 1):

sorry man, I know it's too late and you know it already.
but I will answare .
You can make a image responsive using

```css
img{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-MEzgCTqi2es/X3dZYeZFtuI/AAAAAAAATc0/ltXNshjx26wqPp1bVSMf9R-EWINMpHRYgCLcBGAsYHQ/s16000/A%2Bcommercieal%2BFair%2B6.jpg" alt="Image of Banijjo Mela 2020">
```

then resive screen and see. You can do it also by using media.